# Y Axis Values Out of Order

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, graphing

I am using AlphaVantage API to download data points, which I then convert to a pandas DataFrame.

I want to plot the new DataFrame with a Scatter/Line graph using Plotly.
The graphs seems to come out perfect when plotting them in Google Colab, however, I seem to be unable to replicate my results in PyCharm and Jupiter Notebook.

When plotting in either PyCharm and JN, the Y-Axis values are plotted out of order, like the graph is trying to create as straight of a line as possible (see 2nd image and look closely at y-axis).

Here is a simplified example of the code and graphs:

Exact Same code used in both instances

Desired Outcome (Sample from Colab):
[image: Sample from Colab]

Outcome on PyCharm and JN  (Current Issue Graph):
[image: Current Issue Graph]

See Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


# DATA FROM API
response = requests.get(url='https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo')
response.raise_for_status()
stock_weekly = response.json()['Weekly Time Series']


# CHANGE DATA FORMAT, RENAME COLUMNS AND CONVERT TO DATETIME, FINALLY FLIP TO HAVE DATE IN ASCENDING ORDER
raw_weekly_data = pd.DataFrame(stock_weekly)
weekly_data = raw_weekly_data.T
weekly_data.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
weekly_data.rename(columns={
    'index': 'DATE', 
    '1. open': 'OPEN', 
    '2. high': 'HIGH',
    '3. low': 'LOW',
    '4. close': 'CLOSE',
    '5. volume': 'VOLUME'
    }, 
    inplace=True)
weekly_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(weekly_data['DATE'])
weekly_data = weekly_data[::-1]
weekly_data = weekly_data.reset_index(drop=True)


# PLOT
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=weekly_data['DATE'], 
    y=weekly_data['CLOSE']))

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I received an answer to my question on plotly and decided to share. I used a combination of both of the following techniques:

> The error is due to the data types of your columns in your dataframe.
> dtypes The values are of type object.
>
> However this was not a problem is previous versions of plotly (which
> must be installed on your Google Collab). The newer releases requires
> the values to be numeric.

You can either convert the columns to numeric like this:

```
#converting to type numeric
cols = weekly_data.columns.drop('DATE')
weekly_data[cols] = weekly_data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

or just add autotypenumbers=‘convert types’ to update your figure:

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=weekly_data['DATE'], 
    y=weekly_data['CLOSE']))

fig.update_layout(autotypenumbers='convert types')

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error lies in the data type of your y-axis values. I would guess they are currently strings. Try converting the values to float, and that should solve the problem. To convert all the values in your y-axis to float (which would be the 'CLOSE' column in the dataframe), you can do:

`weekly_data['CLOSE'] = weekly_data['CLOSE'].astype(float)`